# How do I remove DB entries based on text file in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, text-files

I have a list of words in a text file. Each word separated by a new line. I want to read all of the words, and then, for each word I have to look up the DB and remove rows that contain the words that were read from the text file. How do i do that? I am a newbie to DB programming and I guess we dont have loops in SQL, right?

1 - Read all the words from the text file
2 - For each word from the text file
3 - Remove entry from db e.d. delete from TABLE where ITEMNAME is like ' WORDFROMFILE'

Thanks

Comment: If you expect people to invest their time answering your question, YOU should invest some time in asking the question. Your question is broad and tells us nothing about which specific problems you are facing. This is not a code-for-free shop!

Comment: Well I tried and could not do, so thats why I put the question here. I am a newbie to DB so I find it helpful when people answer to even the dumbest of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the general idea:

Step 1: Import the text file into a table.

Step 2: Write a query that `DELETE`s from the target table `WHERE` the keyword `=` the keyword in the target table, using an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: In defence of my answer, pre-empting all the SQL purists, the use of WHERE can be avoided if the JOIN is written correctly :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/) technique to read text from file. If you want to do more complicated stuff, I'd suggest doing it from the front end (eg c#/vb etc.) rather than the db